# How to post array within array with curl

Tags: php, arrays, post, curl

I am trying to use curl with an API and post values to it.
I'm posting the parameters in an associative array where all the values are either strings, integers or booleans apart from one value which is another array. (So there is an array within another array.)

The problem is: the second array isn't being sent properly and I can't get it to work.
Originally the issue was 'array to string conversion' so I then started using http_build_query() around the params array and it stopped that issue but it sill isn't working.

I know it's probably an issue with my code and not the external API as other developers are using the API fine with other languages.

**PHP Code:**

```
    $url = '{url}';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    $headers = array("X-Auth-Token: $json_token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $params = array(
            'name' => 'sample_name',
            'types' => array('web'),
            'limit' => 2,
            'auto' => true
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of [form submission formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) support nested (multi-dimensional) arrays. In other words you **cannot** send nested arrays in POST request as form-encoded data (CURL uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format by default). Most likely you've misinterpreted API specs. Perhaps the API accept data in other format, for instance, [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) which allows any level of nesting.

Comment: Yes! I changed the content type and encoded the array to json and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @user5331188 You could upvote this answer as well if it solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try with `serialize`

```
// Data to post 
$postData = array( 
  'name' = 'foo', 
  'data' = serialize(array(1,2,3,4)), 
  'value' = 'bar' 
); 

// Will not error 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 
?>
```

Check here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99108

Comment: instead of serialize, I used json_encode

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$url = '{url}';
$params = array(
        'name' => 'sample_name',
        'types' => array('web'),
        'limit' => 2,
        'auto' => true
);
$data_string = json_encode($params);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```